# Change title for specific Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need help with something.. 
I have the following function to display the title for the comments section.

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

If I change it to the following: 
`<?php comment_form(array('title_reply' => 'Comment with image' )); ?>` I get the title I want. 
But I only want this for page(2123).. How can I do that?

Comment: And the code of the function is?

Comment: @SuperDJ The function's name is "comment_form". But I only want to array the title if page(2123) but I don't know how to implement that in to the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by page 2123 you mean page id, than

```
<?php if(get_the_ID() == 2123) comment_form(array('title_reply' => 'Comment with image' )); ?>
```

should do the job. This should be called inside the loop.